# DataNotFoundError: Unable to load data for: endpoints

Tags: pandas, dataframe, amazon-s3, boto3, botocore

I'm trying to write from a data frame to CSV directly to an s3 bucket
I've tried the stringIO method but the problem is that I run into the "KeyTooLong" error.

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('s3')
client.create_bucket(Bucket = 'poolpo-rent-a-car-bucket')
# checking if the bucket was created
response = client.list_buckets()
response['Buckets']
bucket_name = 'poolpo-rent-a-car-bucket'
car_costs.to_csv(f"s3://{bucket_name}/{car_costs}.csv")
```

This is the StringIO one

```
from io import StringIO

bucket_name = 'poolpo-rent-a-car-bucket'
csv_buffer = StringIO()
branch_locations.to_csv(csv_buffer)
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_resource.Object(bucket_name, f'{branch_locations}.csv').put(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())
```

And the error

> ClientError: An error occurred (KeyTooLongError) when calling the PutObject operation: Your key is too long

These are medium size dataframes, like 5000 rows and like 3-5 columns

Comment: What do you want to do? `car_costs` is undefined, so your code wont even run.

Comment: my data frame is a query from Postgres so it makes sense that you won't be able to run it, I was just providing a snippet of my code and the error I was having with the two possible solutions that I found in stack.

Answer (score 0):

For an unrelated reason, I had to reinstall anaconda and the problems got away.
Ended up using a way simpler approach.

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('s3')
client.create_bucket(Bucket = 'poolpo-rent-a-car-bucket')
response = client.list_buckets()
response['Buckets']
car_costs.to_csv(f"s3://{bucket_name}/car_costs.csv")
```

One other thing that I noticed in s3 was that when I was using the f string to input the dataframe I was basically using the dataframe as a name hence why I was having the `KeyTooLongError`